# Book on sentence structure/variety

Tags: resources, sentence-structure

Is there a good book on sentence structure and variety?
My goal is to improve the way my sentences flow on the page and to improve the reader experience.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! I'm on the fence as to whether this is on-topic or not; our [official topic guidelines](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) state that shopping questions are off-topic here, but we have plenty of questions from people asking for software that performs various writing-related functions. I think this is fine for now.

Comment: It is on topic because it is asking about where to get advice about improving writing.

Answer (score 1):

**Elements of Style** by Strunkle and White

**Building Great Sentences: How to Write the Kinds of Sentences You Love to Read** by Brooks Landon.  You can watch a portion of the Great Courses series that this book is based on [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-DNwoZmstA)

Answer (score 0):

A book that has helped me tremendously is *On Writing Well* by William F. Zinsser. I'm not sure if it is still in print, but a search of Amazon.com should turn something up.

Answer (score 0):

I can highly recommend *Writing Tools*, by Roy Peter Clark! It strongly focuses on being focused and concise. He uses examples from both fiction and journalism, which is interesting.

I hope it's what you're looking for! It has helped me a lot :)

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! Does this book offer any advice on sentence variety? If not, then I'm afraid it wouldn't be an answer to OP's question.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for checking. It does, among other things that will help OP's writing flow on the page, and improve reader experience :)